# Java. Selenium. Mobile automation. An error occurred while instantiating class <someclass>: null

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I try to run automation script for testing of my Android device (Java+Selenium+Appium). According to the task I should run my test class with extends class (`extends BaseWebDriverTest`). When I run the test without extends everything is OK but with it my test failed with error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
An error occurred while instantiating class auto.test.TestSample: null
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:398)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:115)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:141)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:271)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:575)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:159)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:113)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at auto.framework.pageframework.util.drivers.WebDriverWrapper.<clinit>(WebDriverWrapper.java:67)
    at auto.framework.test.BaseWebDriverTest.<clinit>(BaseWebDriverTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant auto.framework.pageframework.util.environment.Browser.
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at auto.framework.pageframework.util.environment.Browser.valueOf(Browser.java:9)
    at auto.framework.pageframework.util.environment.EnvironmentUtil.setBrowser(EnvironmentUtil.java:877)
    at auto.framework.pageframework.util.environment.EnvironmentUtil.<clinit>(EnvironmentUtil.java:129)
    ... 34 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Appium server works fine.

Here is my code:

```
package auto.test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import auto.framework.test.BaseWebDriverTest;
import auto.pageframework.testdata.TestConstants;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class TestSample extends BaseWebDriverTest {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestSample.class);

    AppiumDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void testSetup() throws MalformedURLException {

        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/wholefoods");
        File app = new File(appDir, "com.wholefoods.wholefoodsmarket.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "J509B1ZB46180A57");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.wholefoods.wholefoodsmarket");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.wholefoods.wholefoodsmarket.application.activities.WFMSplashActivity");
        this.driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @Test(groups = { TestConstants.TestNGGroups.REG }, description = "")
    public void testSearchingForCoffeeFood() {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Boolean searchFieldIsPresent = driver.findElements(By.id("etHomeSearch")).size() > 0;
        Assert.assertTrue(searchFieldIsPresent, "Search field with id='etHomeSearch' is absent.");
        WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.id("etHomeSearch"));
        searchField.clear();
        searchField.sendKeys("Coffee");

        Boolean searchButtonIsPresent = driver.findElements(By.id("imgSearch")).size() > 0;
        Assert.assertTrue(searchButtonIsPresent, "Search button with id='imgSearch' is absent.");
        WebElement searchButton = driver.findElement(By.id("imgSearch"));
        searchButton.click();

        Boolean pageTitleIsPresent = driver.findElement(By.id("header_title")).getText().equals("SEARCH");
        Boolean searchResultIsPresent = driver.findElements(By.id("recipesSearchResultsGrid")).size() > 0;

}
```

Here is the code of extends class:

```
package auto.framework.test;

import auto.framework.pageframework.synchronization.AjaxHelper;
import framework.pageframework.util.drivers.WebDriverWrapper;
import framework.pageframework.util.environment.EnvironmentUtil;
import auto.framework.test.TestListener;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;

@Listeners({TestListener.class})
public class BaseWebDriverTest {
    protected static WebDriver driver = null;
    protected static AjaxHelper syncHelper = new AjaxHelper(WebDriverWrapper.getWebDriver());
    protected static EnvironmentUtil env = EnvironmentUtil.getInstance();
    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BaseWebDriverTest.class);

    public BaseWebDriverTest() {
    }

    @AfterClass(
        alwaysRun = true
    )
    public static void suiteTearDown() {
        if(!env.getIsRemoteTestRun()) {
            WebDriverWrapper.closeBrowser(driver);
        }

    }

    @AfterMethod(
        alwaysRun = true
    )
    public void testTearDown() {
        logger.warn("========================== Completed test ==============================");
    }

    static {
        logger.info("calling get WebDriver()");
        driver = WebDriverWrapper.getWebDriver();
    }
}
```

Here is my `Browser` class:

```
public enum Browser {
    FIREFOX,
    CHROME,
    SAFARI,
    IE,
    LOCAL_SIMULATED_NEXUS_SEVEN,
    LOCAL_SIMULATED_IPAD_THREE,
    BS_FIREFOX_31,
    BS_FIREFOX_35_LS,
    BS_IE_10,
    BS_IE_11,
    BS_IE_11_LS,
    BS_CHROME_36,
    BS_CHROME_39,
    BS_CHROME_39_LS,
    BS_SAFARI_7_MAC,
    LOCAL_NEXUS_SEVEN_MOBILE_WEB,
    LOCAL_NEXUS_SEVEN_DEVICE,
    LOCAL_ANDROID_MOBILE,
    LOCAL_ANDROID_TABLET,
    SIM_IPAD_MOBILE_WEB,
    SIM_IPHONE_MOBILE_WEB,
    LOCAL_SIM_IPHONE_FIVE,
    LOCAL_SIM_IPHONE_FIVE_S,
    LOCAL_SIM_IPHONE_SIX,
    LOCAL_SIM_IPHONE_SIX_PLUS,
    LOCAL_SIM_IPAD,
    LOCAL_IPAD_DEVICE,
    LOCAL_IPHONE_DEVICE,
    LOCAL_GENERIC_DEVICE,
    LOCAL_GENERIC_DRIVER,
    REMOTE_CHROME,
    REMOTE_FIREFOX,
    REMOTE_INTERNETEXPLORER,
    REMOTE_SAFARI,
    REMOTE_SIMULATED_NEXUS_SEVEN,
    REMOTE_SIMULATED_IPAD,
    APPTHWACK_SAFARI_IOS,
    APPTHWACK_NEXUS_SEVEN,
    APPTHWACK_NEXUS_FIVE,
    APPTHWACK_IPHONE_SIX,
    APPTHWACK_IPAD_FOUR,
    TD_NEXUS_SEVEN_CHROME_WEB,
    TD_NEXUS_SEVEN,
    TD_NEXUS_FIVE,
    TD_GALAXY_S_THREE,
    TD_IPAD_SAFARI_WEB,
    TD_IPAD,
    TD_IPHONE_SIX;

    private Browser() {
    }
}
```

and this is the part of `EnvironmentUtil`:

```
public class EnvironmentUtil {
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EnvironmentUtil.class);
private static Browser browser;
private static String deviceName;
private static String platformVersion;
private static String url;
private static String testPlanId;
private static String testRunId;
private static String snapshotDirectory;
private static Boolean takeSnapShots = Boolean.valueOf(true);
private static Boolean setLogToDebug = Boolean.valueOf(false);
private static Boolean logResults = Boolean.valueOf(false);
private static Boolean failedTestDoReset = Boolean.valueOf(false);
private static String webDriverGridUrl = "";
private static Boolean isMobileTest = Boolean.valueOf(false);
private static int appThwackProjectId = 0;
private static String appThwackApiKey = "";
private static int appThwackAppId = 0;
private static String appiumGridUrl;
private static String appPackage;
private static String appActivity;
private static String testDroidUserName = "";
private static String testDroidPassword = "";
private static String testDroidProjectName = "";
private static String testDroidProjectDescription = "";
private static String testDroidTestRun = "";
private static String testDroidServer = "";
private static String targetAppPath = "";
private static String testGroup = "";
private static boolean rawCssOnly = false;
private static String previousWindowHandle = "";
private static boolean isMobileIOS = false;
private static boolean isTablet = false;
private static boolean isPhablet = false;
private static boolean isSimulator = false;
private static boolean isPhone = false;
private static boolean isAndroidTablet = false;
private static String browserStackUserName = "";
private static String browserStackKey = "";
private static String iosBundleID = "";
private static String iosUdid = "";
private static boolean noSign = false;
private static boolean isJenkinsRun = false;
private static String jenkinsURL = "";
private static boolean isRemoteTestRun = false;
private static String dataProvider = "null";
private static String testRailUrl = "";
private static String testRailUserName = "";
private static String testRailPassword = "";
private static Map<String, String> locators = new HashMap();
private static boolean sizzleInjection = false;
private static String caseId = "";
private static EnvironmentUtil instance = new EnvironmentUtil();

public static EnvironmentUtil getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
```

Help me please how can I fix this problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your class EnvironmentUtil tries to use an enum called Browser and is referring to a value there that is not valid (may be null). In your class BaseWebDriverTest you have a line

```
protected static EnvironmentUtil env = EnvironmentUtil.getInstance();
```

That fails to run and because it is static the whole class cannot load

Comment: I have added information about `Browser` and `EnvironmentUtil` classes. Help me please to fix this problem :(